# What are some good examples of geospatial UI's

Tags: postgis, web-mapping, leaflet, ux

I am interested in understanding and applying practical geo-spatial examples for some of the transportation data that I have. I have several geocodes that I will pull from the database, and display in maps - as map clusters and points, similar to Redfin.

I want to unlock more value of my data - for instance allow the user to draw a ploygon and compute the number of points inside the polygon. Click on 2 markers and display distance etc. This makes the map more feature rich as opposed to a simple cluster of markers.

I like what leaflet offers and the abilities in Postgres/PostGIS to issue geospatial queries, and I am looking to build UI where users can query in a more intuitive mouse click and drag operations. Please point me to some good examples or sites that have implemented this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the things you've mentioned is easily do-able in web mapping APIs like ArcGIS Server JS API and OpenLayers. For example:

- [select features using a polygon](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/select-feature.html)
- [cluster point features](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/strategy-cluster.html)
- [calculate distance between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109620/openlayers-how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-points)

It would be relatively simple to stitch all of this functionality together.

Comment: Nice. Openlayers seems to have most of what I am looking for. I rather stick to that, as I need to present google, live and ArcGIS maps as basemap options.

Answer (score 1):

[Example of Desktop like UI](http://etat.geneve.ch/geoportail/geocadastre/) using ExtJS and Openlayers

Comment: Can you share more examples? While this site has a ton of features, I am looking for something more simple. An easy way to draw, measure, query points inside polugon etc.

Comment: sorry for being late but the second answer may be the answer